# Dividing two rows by different groupings

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to run an update statement that calculates a percentage. What I want to do is basically get the amount of units that have a multisourcecode of 'y' and divide them by the total amount of units that dont have a multisourcecode of 'y'. I can get it down to the groupings for units and multisourcecode, but am having trouble doing the actual calculations from there. Below is the code.

```
update erosiondata2
set Erosion1 = 

(select     
    sum(Units) TotalUnits,
    MultiSourceCode
from 
    wkdata2 w join mddb m on w.ndc11 = m.ndc join ErosionData2 e on e.genprodident = m.genprodident
where 
    e.GenProdIdent = '44505080000310' and m.RepckgCode <> 'x' and w.RecordDate = e.GenericLaunchDate
group by 
    MultiSourceCode)
```

I could also run it like the way below, but it takes FOREVER.

```
update erosiondata2
set genericlaunchdate = 

select  
    (select sum(Units) from wkdata2 w join mddb m on w.ndc11 = m.ndc join ErosionData2 e on e.genprodident = m.genprodident
    where erosiondata2.genprodident = m.GenProdIdent and m.RepckgCode <> 'x' and w.RecordDate = e.GenericLaunchDate and MultiSourceCode = 'Y') / sum(t.units)

FROM
(select SUM(units) Units from wkdata2 w join mddb m on w.ndc11 = m.ndc join ErosionData2 e on e.genprodident = m.genprodident
    where erosiondata2.genprodident = m.GenProdIdent and m.RepckgCode <> 'x' and w.RecordDate = e.GenericLaunchDate and MultiSourceCode <> 'y') t
```

Here is the code that works. It takes awhile to run, though.

```
update erosiondata2
set Erosion1 = 

(Select 
    SUM(Case When MultiSourceCode = 'Y' Then TotalUnits Else 0 End) / SUM(TotalUnits)
FROM
    (select     
        MultiSourceCode,
        sum(Units) TotalUnits

    from 
        wkdata2 w join mddb m on w.ndc11 = m.ndc join ErosionData2 e on e.genprodident = m.genprodident
    where 
        erosiondata2.genprodident = m.GenProdIdent and m.RepckgCode <> 'x' and w.RecordDate = e.GenericLaunchDate
    group by 
        MultiSourceCode)t)
```

Comment: Attached is the new code. It still takes awhile to run, though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
With MultiSourceCodeUnits as (
    select     
        MultiSourceCode,
        sum(Units) TotalUnits

    from 
        wkdata2 w join mddb m on w.ndc11 = m.ndc join ErosionData2 e on e.genprodident = m.genprodident
    where 
        e.GenProdIdent = '44505080000310' and m.RepckgCode <> 'x' and w.RecordDate = e.GenericLaunchDate
    group by 
        MultiSourceCode
)
Select MultiSourceCode,
       TotalUnits / SUM(Case When MultiSourceCode <> 'Y' Then TotalUnits Else 0 End)
FROM MultiSourceCodeUnits
```

Comment: In your case, GP, it is extremely unlikely that you will end up with no rows that do not have a multisource code, which is why @Sarin hasn't bothered to check for zero; but in most cases, users will want to check for zero before dividing.

Comment: How would I include this in the update statement. Where should I put    update erosiondata2
set Erosion1 =

Comment: Add the update statement just above "select multi source code, total units. .."

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH  CTE as 
(SELECT sum(Units) TotalUnits, MultiSourceCode
FROM wkdata2 w 
INNER JOIN  mddb m 
  on w.ndc11 = m.ndc 
INNER JOIN ErosionData2 e 
  on e.genprodident = m.genprodident
where e.GenProdIdent = '44505080000310' 
  and m.RepckgCode <> 'x' 
  and w.RecordDate = e.GenericLaunchDate
group by MultiSourceCode)

SELECT (Select cte.totalUnits from CTE where MultiSourceCode = 'Y') / 
    (Select cte.totalUnits from CTE where coalesce(MultiSourceCode,'N') <> 'Y' )
```

I think this should give you the correct math.  from here you can probably figure out the update.